# Synonymous terms for a "reciprocal interaction / incorporation"

Tags: synonyms

How does one define, succinctly, an interaction between two objects A and B where ideas from A are used to improve B and vice versa?

Thanks.

Comment: Objects like A or B don't have ideas. People have ideas.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's a good point. I should have written "two subjects or fields A and B...".

Comment: Ah, you're talking about academic jargon. _Subject_ and _field_ both have too many meanings, too. So a linguist and a biologist have coffee together, sort of thing? What can they talk about? Mimicry? Symbiosis? Punctuated evolution? Phonetics?

Comment: @JohnLawler Explicitly, A and B are two "branches" of mathematics. They have some overlap but are different in general due to the methods and goals. I want to talk about the exchange of certain disparate methods from one branch to the other: embedding one method into a method of the other branch.

Comment: @Hikaru I was going to suggest mutual benefit or symbiosis, but I see the latter answer below. BTW, In Haruki Murakami's novel Killing Commendatore, one of the characters is an "idea" and the idea has many helpful ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The word **symbiotic** is usually used to describe a mutually beneficial behaviour. Maybe the context of the question can help provide an appropriate suggestion.

**Symbiotic:**
characterized by or being a close, cooperative, or interdependent relationship

Example: Today, art advisers are as diverse as the clients they help. They often work alone and form intimate, symbiotic relationships with the people they serve.

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/symbiotic

Comment: You should include an authoritative dictionary definition for you chosen word and an explantion of how it fits the question. If you need more clarity for a better anwser, you should wait for the question to be updated before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found several examples from business blogs where the verb **cross-pollinate** is used as a metaphor for the sort of thing you are describing.

https://www.fastcompany.com/1672519/5-ways-to-innovate-by-cross-pollinating-ideas

https://www.growthengineering.co.uk/cross-pollination-in-business/

Merriam-Webster even gives the following secondary sense to the synonym  **cross-fertilization**:

> 1a: fertilization in which the gametes are produced by separate individuals or sometimes by individuals of different kinds
>
> **2: interchange or interaction (as between different ideas, cultures, or categories) especially of a broadening or productive nature**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross-fertilization

Clearly these terms from biology are often used for the situation you are describing.